# Почему свойство undefined

Tags: javascript

Почему я получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

По идеи код должен вернуть оружие или написать что его нет, если такого нет в массиве **swords**

```
var armory = {};
var swords = ["broadsword", "Katana", "Claymore", "Scimitar"];

armory.retrieveSword = function (request) {
  return (this.swords.indexOf(request) >= 0) ?
          this.swords.splice(this.swords.indexOf(request), 1)[0] :
          console.log("No " + request + ", baby");
};

var isKnight = true;
var weapon = isKnight && armory.retrieveSword("Katana");
console.log(weapon);
```

Comment: `var swords = ...`  ->  `armory.swords = ...`

Comment: Очевидно, потому что `this.swords == undefined`. А вот почему оно так - из вашего кода не ясно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что внутри функции *retrieveSword*, *this* ссылается на объект *armory*, у которого нет свойства *this.swords* и по этому у вас *undefined*.

Вместо

```
var swords = ["broadsword", "Katana", "Claymore", "Scimitar"];
```

Вам нужно написать

```
armory.swords = ["broadsword", "Katana", "Claymore", "Scimitar"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) swords находится в глобальном объекте
2) this указывает на armory.retrieveSword

Чесно говоря мне сложно судить о том, каким код был задуман, но кажется можно поступить так:

```
var armory = function() {
    this.swords = ["broadsword", "Katana", "Claymore", "Scimitar"];
    var self = this;
    this.retrieveSword = function (request) {
        return (self.swords.indexOf(request) >= 0) ?
            self.swords.splice(self.swords.indexOf(request), 1)[0] :
                console.log("No " + request + ", baby");
    };
};
```

Comment: ой вэй, раз уж поменял способ создания объекта, надо было добавлять и измененный пример использования, не говоря уже о том, что в данном случае не обязательно сохранять `this` в конструкторе. В данном случае проблема не в потере контекста

Comment: Он не изменился...

Comment: Ну ладно Вам, контекст this в функции retrieveSword изменился!

Comment: очевидно изменился: теперь `armory` - это функция, которая может быть конструктором, в коде в вопросе  `armory` - это сам объект, поэтому если использовать функцию как объект - код не будет работать как ожидается.

Comment: очевидно, что не изменился - он как был ссылкой на armory, так ей и остался

Comment: А када тогда девалса this функции retrieveSword?

Comment: _this_ никуда не девался, он всегда был

Comment: Используется контекст в котором присутствует swords, а не контекст  функции retrieveSword

Comment: вообще нет, используется контекст armory, в котором функции swords как раз нет, собственно в этом и состоит вопрос.

Comment: это понятно, прочем ответ получен и код работает, поэтому предлагаю завершить...

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо разобрался. Теперь код работает как и было задумано, а именно:

> код возвращает оружие если оно есть в массиве **swords**, и сообщение об ошибке если указанного оружия нет - метод **armory.retrieveSword()**.

```
var armory = {
  swords: ["Broadsword", "Katana", "Claymore", "Scimitar"],
  addSword: function (swords) {
    this.swords = this.swords || [];
    this.swords.push(swords);
  }
};

armory.retrieveSword = function (request) {
  return (this.swords.indexOf(request) >= 0) ?
          this.swords.splice(this.swords.indexOf(request), 1)[0] :
          alert("No " + request + ", baby!");
};

var isKnight = true;
var weapon = isKnight && armory.retrieveSword("123");
console.log(weapon);
```